# Parse data in JSON format

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON string which JSON lint says is valid, however, I am having a hell of a time just accessing its values.

```
var json='{"currentVersion":10.2,"folders":["Canvas","Demographics","Elevation","Ocean","Reference","Specialty","Utilities"],"services":[{"name":"ESRI_Imagery_World_2D","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"I3_Imagery_Prime_World","type":"GlobeServer"},{"name":"NASA_CloudCover_World","type":"GlobeServer"},{"name":"NatGeo_World_Map","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"NGS_Topo_US_2D","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"Ocean_Basemap","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"USA_Topo_Maps","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"World_Imagery","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"World_Physical_Map","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"World_Shaded_Relief","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"World_Street_Map","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"World_Terrain_Base","type":"MapServer"},{"name":"World_Topo_Map","type":"MapServer"}]}'
```

For example, how can I access the value of currentVersion ?

I tried `json.currentVersion` but it returns `{`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a JSON string, which is what you've got,  you can't really access anything, you have to parse it first

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

obj.currentVersion
```